# Add a column to an IEnumerable in c#

Tags: c#, linq, webmatrix

I don't think I can actually add a field (column) to an existing IEnumerable.  But what I want is a new IEnumerable that is derived from an existing IEnumerable with a calculated field.  The pseudocode in WebMatrix using Web Pages looks like:

```
var db = Database.Open("LOS");
var ie = db.Query(sqlAssignments);

// make a new ie2 that has an extra field
// ??? ie2 <=== ie with new field c = ie.a + ie.b

var grid = new WebGrid( ie2, extra parameters );
```

I know how to do this looping through all the rows in ie.  But I'm hoping there's something more elegant.

Comment: IEnumerable simply signifies an enumerable type, i.e. a consumer can enumerate through it's constituent items. It has no concept of 'fields' or 'columns'.

Comment: @Adam - yet I think more people are likely to understand *that* title than, for example: "Use a projection to create a new sequence based on an old sequence, but with additional members"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
var ie2 = ie.Select(x => new { x.Foo, x.Bar, Sum = x.Abc + x.Def });
var grid = new WebGrid(ie2);
```

Comment: this works great, but bizarrely has led to a new problem where the WebGrid no longer automatically sorts  :( .   I decided to make it a new question.

Comment: @Knox - just use ie2.ToList()

Comment: I tried ToList, but it still didn't sort.  Rather than morph this question into the new question, i asked a new question.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339335/add-a-column-to-an-ienumerable-in-c-such-that-it-works-with-webgrid

Comment: that's kind of a pain: what if you have like 20 columns or more?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `Select`. Try this:

```
ie2 = ie.Select( e => new { IE = e, NewParam =  e.X+e.Y });
```

Comment: The one comment I have about this is that most data-binding only looks one level down; you usually need to flatten the properties of `e`, otherwise you'll just have a column named `e` with `e.ToString()` as the values.

Comment: If that is the case, you will have to flatten as your answer depicts. If it only looks down one level, let's hope the number of properties on `e` is manageable :)

Comment: I didn't get this to immediately work, and decided to flatten it.  Fortunately, there are only about 10 properties on e.

Answer (score 3):

```
ie2 = ie.Select(v => new {v.a, v.b, c = v.a + v.b});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq!

```
var newIe = from item in ie
            select new {item.NewField, item.OldFiedl1 etc... }
```

Also, probably best (if you intend to use outside this method) to make that anonymous type named.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `IEnumerable` is probably a list of *something* - an object. That is the object you can extend.

You can probably do something like this:

```
var ie = db.Query( ... );
var ie2 = ie.Select(i => new MyIe2Object {
   Prop1 = i.Prop1,
   NewProp = i.Prop1 + i.Prop2
});
```

Comment: When LINQ gets involved, I don't think it is true to guess a "list" - but sure, extending the *something* would work, too

Comment: The point is that it's not really about extending the `IEnumerable`, but the *something*.